# Wake up an Xbox 360 with a TV remote

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

As I understand it, HDMI is capable of sending "control" signals that can force a device at least *into* standby mode.  I've also heard it can reset devices and even control certain models of bluray/dvd player.

My question is, can this be used with the Xbox 360 in order to power up the device using a TV remote instead of one of the wireless controllers?

My reason for asking is that my wireless controller won't turn the device on if it's plugged in (charging), only if it's unplugged - and since the charge pack has now died, it's always plugged in (charging) so I can't turn the xbox on remotely.

I realise this is virtually the epitome of laziness, but I'm asking more out of curiosity than anything (no, really...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a normal TV remote control, it's unlikely.  Those remotes are only meant to control the TV they come with, and are programmed with a special control code to ensure only the TV responds to the IR commands.  This is why you need to program universal remotes to work with your TV if you lose its remote.

It's possible with programmable remotes like the [Logitech Harmony](http://www.logitech.com/remotes/universal-remotes) series.  My friend has his entire entertainment center (TV, receiver, and Xbox) all turn on with the press of a single button.  The remotes are expensive, but doing what you're asking is definitely possible.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question - I was asking about whether a standard TV remote can wake up an Xbox 360 via HDMI; do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @ChrisBrowne It appears that I did slightly misunderstand your question.  I edited my answer above

Comment: ok, thanks for your help :) I guess I'll have to be un-lazy in that case!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about other remotes, but I have the [Xbox 360 Universal Media Remote](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/universal-media-remote) (older version), and it works perfectly for turning on the 360, and you can use it for programming your TV and other devices.

There is a [newer version](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Xbox360/Accessories/Controllers/Xbox360MediaRemote) ($19.99 MSRP), which I would assume works the same.

Comment: see my comment on Dave McClelland's answer

Comment: @ChrisBrowne Yep, didn't read it as using the standard remote, Sorry. For $19.99 it's not a bad deal though.

Comment: Not something I can afford at the moment, but we have talked about getting one when we have a bit more spare cash :)